# Cannot display AdMob banner

Tags: android

I need to put at the bottom of my view the AdMob banner and above it the ScrollView for the content, in tis way the banner shoud always be visibile.

The problemis that my ScrollView fill the whole screen and the logcat sys that I have no space to display the banner.

This is the logcat:

```
03-14 10:22:56.342    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
03-14 10:22:56.352    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
03-14 10:22:56.352    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
03-14 10:22:56.352    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
03-14 10:22:56.352    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/chromium﹕ [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
03-14 10:22:57.282    1664-1695/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform
03-14 10:23:08.692    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <720, 100>, Has: <720, 0>
```

This is my Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <!-- Consiglio 1 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                    <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/img1"
                            android:background="@drawable/uno"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/testoUno"
                            android:text="Consiglio 1"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Consiglio 1 -->

            <!-- Consiglio 2 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/testoDue"
                    android:text="Consiglio 2"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img2"
                    android:background="@drawable/due"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Consiglio 2 -->

            <!-- Consiglio 3 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img3"
                    android:background="@drawable/tre"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/testoTre"
                    android:text="Consiglio 3"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Consiglio 3 -->

            <!-- Consiglio 4 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/testoQuattro"
                    android:text="Consiglio 4"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img4"
                    android:background="@drawable/quattro"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Consiglio 4 -->

            <!-- Consiglio 5 -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/img5"
                    android:background="@drawable/cinque"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/testoCinque"
                    android:text="Consiglio 5"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- /Consiglio 5 -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
        <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-*********/*******"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            android:gravity="bottom">

        </com.google.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't understand what I'm missing. Any help is really appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your `ScrollView`'s height is defined this way: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. So basically, as you have too much things in your layout, it takes all the screen and leaves no space for the `AdView`.

Probably forcing the `height` of your `AdView` to be 100, should show that banner, as right now, as you see, it has no space.

Comment: Ok I have set the height but to show it I need to git a fixed heigth also at the ScrollView.
How can I modify it to fix the admob at bottom and let the scrollview at the top?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set a fixed height to the `ScrollView`, just let it as a `wrap_content`. This will make the height as big as possible, but as you're fixing the height of your `AdView`, it will be forced to reduce the height so your ad will show up.

Comment: with the wrap_content the scrollview fit the whole screen and the adview does not shows up

Comment: Try using a different approach: Instead using `layout_height`, use `layout_weight="4"` for the `ScrollView` and `layout_weight="1"` for the `AdView`. If it doesn't fit, play around with the proportions until it's what you're looking for, this way you're not hardcoding sizes but you're playing with display proportions.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is here:

```
03-14 10:23:08.692    1664-1664/com.elisafedeli.consiglipergenitori.app E/Ads﹕ Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <720, 100>, Has: <720, 0>
```

Set the min-height of the container to 100dp. May as well set the main width, while you're at it.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, as I told at the other user I have set the haight but the adView still do not shows up

Comment: try setting the scrollview to have a layout_height of 0dp and a layout_weight of 1